# Android Studio CardView is always transparent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview

I am trying to use Cardview but it somehow doesnt show the background, its always tranparent.
I tried to change the background with cardBackgroundColor but it doesnt work, it stays transparent.
How can i change the background?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjdmP.png)

Comment: write a code in text, not in the image, it'll be easier to help You

Comment: You probably don't have `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in the root xml tag of the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it isnt picking up `cardBackgroundColor` because you dont have the `app` namespace. Ensure you have the `app` namespace in the top container element of your layout

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`